# Heartbeat doesn't start

Tags: 10.04, installation, server, upstart

Heartbeat don't start on automatic.
Network interface is not UP when heartbeat start

OS version : 10.04

Exact message in boot.log :

```
Starting High-Availability services: bond1: unknown interface: No such device

/usr/lib/heartbeat/findif version 2.99.1 Copyright Alan Robertson

Usage: /usr/lib/heartbeat/findif [-C]
Options:
    -C: Output netmask as the number of bits rather than as 4 octets.
Environment variables:
OCF_RESKEY_ip ip address (mandatory!)
OCF_RESKEY_cidr_netmask netmask of interface
OCF_RESKEY_broadcast broadcast address for interface
OCF_RESKEY_nic interface to assign to
IPaddr2[1820]: WARNING: [/usr/lib/heartbeat/findif -C] failed
IPaddr2[1795]: INFO: Resource is stopped
 Heartbeat failure [rc=6]. Failed.

heartbeat[1868]: 2011/02/23_10:04:23 ERROR: glib: Get broadcast for interface bond1 failed: No such device
heartbeat[1868]: 2011/02/23_10:04:23 ERROR: glib: IP interface [bond1] does not exist
```

Comment: This question should instead be filed as a bug report, thanks! [Instructions here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).

Answer (score 0):

This looks like you've hit this known bug:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/heartbeat/+bug/567463

Its been in progress for over a year, so maybe Andres has forgotten about it. Please add your experience to the bug report, as it may help Andres figure it out.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something here, but this doesn't look like that bug.

Comment: Good point, i suppose its actually just that heartbeat is starting before all network interfaces are up.